# Implement an AndroidX Worker with custom parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-workmanager

I'm migrating from the [Android Priority JobQueue library](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue) to the AndroidX `WorkManager` in my project, but it is built in a way that the `Worker` should be something like this:

**TaskSchedulerWorker.kt**

```
class TaskSchedulerWorker(
    private val workManager: WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
) : TaskScheduler {

    override fun execute(useCaseWrapper: UseCaseWrapper) {
        workManager.beginUniqueWork(
            useCaseWrapper.useCaseName,
            ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
            OneTimeWorkRequest.from(UseCaseWrapperWorker::class.java)
        ).enqueue()
    }

    override fun onCancel(useCaseWrapper: UseCaseWrapper) {
        workManager.cancelUniqueWork(useCaseWrapper.useCaseName)
    }
}
```

**UseCaseWrapperWorker.kt**

```
class UseCaseWrapperWorker(
    context: Context, 
    params: WorkerParams,
    private val useCaseWrapper: UseCaseWrapper
) : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            useCaseWrapper.execute()
            Result.success()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            Result.failure()
        }
    }
}
```

The point is that if I try to run my app with those classes, I receive the next error:

```
2019-05-09 09:34:45.784 27260-27443/com.mobileapp.debug E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.mobileapp.domain.jobqueue.UseCaseWrapperWorker
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mobileapp.domain.jobqueue.UseCaseWrapperWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2328)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2167)
        at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:92)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:234)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-05-09 09:34:45.784 27260-27443/com.mobileapp.debug E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Could not create Worker com.mobileapp.domain.jobqueue.UseCaseWrapperWorker
```

Because the `Worker` constructor can not have more than the two default parameters (`Context` and `WorkerParameters`).

I am not able to figure out how to implement the `UseCaseWrapperWorker` class with a constructor that receives the `Context`, the `WorkerParameters` and the `UseCaseWrapper`, and invoke it from the `TaskSchedulerWorker` with the `OneTimeWorkRequest.from(UseCaseWrapperWorker::class.java)` instruction.

---

**EDITED:**

I've tried to implement a `CustomWorkerFactory` and a `CustomWorker` to pass them the `UseCaseWrapper`. The problem is that I have to init the `WorkManager` in the `Application#onCreate` method ([Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkManager#initialize)), and I don't have access to the `UseCaseWrapper` needed at this point.

**TaskSchedulerWorker.kt**

(the `WorkManager` init should be in `Application#onCreate`)

```
class TaskSchedulerWorker(private val appContext: Context) : TaskScheduler {

    override fun execute(useCaseWrapper: UseCaseWrapper) {
        val workerFactory = CustomWorkerFactory(useCaseWrapper)
        val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
        WorkManager.initialize(context, configuration)

        WorkManager.getInstance().beginWork(
            "uniqueWorkName",
            ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
            OneTimeWorkRequest.from(CustomWorker::class.java)
        )
    }
}
```

**CustomWorkerFactory.kt**

```
class CustomWorkerFactory(private val useCaseWrapper: UseCaseWrapper) : WorkerFactory() {

    override fun createWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerClassName: String,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker? {
        return CustomWorker(appContext, workerParameters, useCaseWrapper)
    }
}
```

**CustomWorker.kt**

```
class CustomWorker(
    context: Context, 
    params: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, params) {

    private var useCaseWrapper: UseCaseWrapper? = null

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        params: WorkerParameters,
        useCaseWrapper: UseCaseWrapper
    ) : this(context, params) {
        this.useCaseWrapper = useCaseWrapper
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return useCaseWrapper?.let { useCaseWrapper ->
            try {
                useCaseWrapper.execute()
                Result.success()
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Result.failure()
            }
        } ?: Result.failure()
    }
}
```

The `RuntimeException` thrown is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobileapp.debug/com.mobileapp.home.view.activity.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  
Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class levelJavadoc for more information.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? 
See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class levelJavadoc for more information.
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:137)
    at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:169)
    at com.mobileapp.domain.worker.TaskSchedulerWorker.execute(TaskSchedulerWorker.kt:20)
    at com.mobileapp.domain.usecase.UseCaseHandler.execute(UseCaseHandler.kt:41)
    at com.mobileapp.domain.usecase.UseCaseCall.execute(UseCaseCall.kt:50)
    at com.mobileapp.home.view.presenter.HomePresenter.getConfigurationJSON(HomePresenter.kt:107)
    at com.mobileapp.home.view.activity.HomeActivity.initComponents(HomeActivity.kt:107)
    at com.mobileapp.home.view.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:67)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am facing the same issue `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:` for the customer parameter in worker implementation. Were you able to fix this one?

Comment: I was trying to resolve the same issue and used your code as example. Only disabled the default initializer from the manifest file and it is running periodic.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom WorkerFactory to initialize your Workers. See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkerFactory

Comment: Ok, that solves the half of the problem. The `WorkManager` have to be initialised in the `Application.onCreate()` method, an at that point I don't have access to my `UseCaseWrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to disable the default initializer

> If you want to control the initialization process, you must disable
>   the default initializer, then define your own custom configuration.
>
> **Disabling the default initializer**
>
> To provide your own configuration,
>   you must first remove the default initializer.
>   To do so, update AndroidManifest.xml using the merge rule
>   tools:node="remove":

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration